# binding model to selected values instead of setting selected on item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code which works fine:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="">TurbineNumber</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
            <li style="padding-left:10px;" ng-repeat="c in turbineNumbersDistinct">
                <label style="font-weight:100;">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.Selected" ng-change="filterChanged()" />&nbsp;{{c.Name}}
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

However I would like to bind the selected value to a new array instead of setting Selected on the object it self. I have found some samples that calls a function that fills the bound array, but isn't it possible to do this inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, using `ng-change` you can push or splice the element into the new output array(`$scope.output`).

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="">TurbineNumber</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
            <li style="padding-left:10px;" ng-repeat="c in turbineNumbersDistinct">
                <label style="font-weight:100;">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-change="selected[$index] ? output.push(c.Name): output.splice(output.indexOf(c.Name), 1)"  />&nbsp;{{c.Name}}
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{output}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Spot on!. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your the go to angular guy :D Do you know if selected works in directives? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139314/using-selected-in-a-directive

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that?

```
ng-model="newArray[$index]"
```

This will bind the input in to the array in the index of the iteration.