# Using selected in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have following that works perfectly in my controller. But when adding it to a directive it dosent work, and I expect it to be that selected dosent work in directives.

```
directive("multiSelectList", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            datasource: "=",
            datasourceSelected: "="
        },
        template: 
        "<div class='col-md-12'> \
            <div class='button-group'> \
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-block btn-sm dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><span class=''>TurbineNumber</span> <span class='caret'></span></button> \
                <ul class='dropdown-menu' style=''> \
                    <li style='padding-left:10px;' ng-repeat='c in datasource'> \
                        <label style='font-weight:100;'> \
                            <input type='checkbox' ng-model='selected[$index]' ng-change='selected[$index] ? datasourceSelected.push(c.Name): datasourceSelected.splice(datasourceSelected.indexOf(c.Name), 1)' />&nbsp;{{c.Name}} \
                        </label> \
                    </li> \
                </ul> \
            </div> \
        </div>"
    };
});
```

Comment: Shoud it not be? "But when adding it to a directive it doesn't work, and I expect it to be that selected  works in directives"

Comment: @Thomas It works fine??? can you check this?  [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/99hj09v5/1/) Please let me know the reason for it not working!

Comment: Argh you directed me in the right direction. It was my attribute naming. I had selectedDatasource instead of selected-datasource. Thanks again. Pls post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue must be in the declaration of the directive, please use the below HTML.

```
<multi-select-list datasource="turbineNumbersDistinct" datasource-selected="output">
</multi-select-list>
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>